# Comparing doubles returns false

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have three numbers from my database and want to compare them in an if statement.

I have a simple conevert function that returns only doubles.

```
Public Function RetDbl(ByVal obj As Variant) As Double
    On Error Resume Next
    RetDbl = val(Replace(Nz(obj, 0), ",", "."))
End Function
```

The statement is

```
If RetDbl(rs.value("NumA")) + RetDbl(rs.value("NumB")) <> (RetDbl(rs.value("NumC")) * 1000) Then
    '[... do some code ...]
End If
```

With `RetDbl(rs.value("NumA")) = 0.33`, `RetDbl(rs.value("NumB") = 0.5` and `RetDbl(rs.value("NumC")) = 0.00083`

**This always returns false**

*I also tried:*

In the direct field (STRG + G): `?cdbl(0.33) + cdbl(0.50) = cdbl(0.83)` returns `false`. When i leave out the last part it returns `0.83`

How can i compare these numbers?

Comment: floating point numbers aren't exact values. Hence comparing them with exact values is likely to fail (as you discovered). It is better to check if `|a - b| < epsilon`for some appropriate epsilon

Comment: I should use this, i guess. But it has worked so far for some days now. Even when i type `?0.33 + 0.50 = 0.83`i only get false. And i never told the program that these were doubles.

Comment: @Ronald is correct.  0.33 + 0.5 = 0.8300000000000001. You can also try rounding or truncation to only compare the significant parts of the floating point numbers.  See [this website](http://floating-point-gui.de/) for a lot of good info on how floating point numbers behave in computer programs.

Comment: @Ronald note that the use of a relative epsilon is recommended if you're creating a function to do the comparison

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth yes, I know. That's why I wrote "some appropriate epsilon". Usually you have something like 8-12 digits of precision (but that can be much worse, depending on the history; if it's a result of a numerically unstable algorithm, you can end up with anything), hence comparing with `10^-8 * a` could be an appropriate value. Since I don't know anything about the "history" of the number, I'm a bit careful with publishing numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comparing floating numbers is hard. Only yesterday, I've posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47789884/7296893)

My solution:

```
Public Function DblSafeCompare(ByVal Value1 As Variant, ByVal Value2 As Variant) As Boolean
    'Compares two variants, dates and floats are compared at high accuracy
    Const AccuracyLevel As Double = 0.00000001
    'We accept an error of 0.000001% of the value
    Const AccuracyLevelSingle As Single = 0.0001
    'We accept an error of 0.0001 on singles
    If VarType(Value1) <> VarType(Value2) Then Exit Function
    Select Case VarType(Value1)
        Case vbSingle
            DblSafeCompare = Abs(Value1 - Value2) <= (AccuracyLevelSingle * Abs(Value1))
        Case vbDouble
            DblSafeCompare = Abs(Value1 - Value2) <= (AccuracyLevel * Abs(Value1))
        Case vbDate
            DblSafeCompare = Abs(CDbl(Value1) - CDbl(Value2)) <= (AccuracyLevel * Abs(CDbl(Value1)))
        Case vbNull
            DblSafeCompare = True
        Case Else
            DblSafeCompare = Value1 = Value2
    End Select
End Function
```

Note that the AccuracyLevel (epsilon) could be set to a smaller value, and I'm using the same value for singles and doubles, but it did well for my purposes.

I'm using a relative epsilon, but multiplying it with the first, and not the largest value, since if there's a significant difference the comparison will fail anyway.

Note that I'm using `<=` and not `<` since else `DblSafeCompare(cdbl(0) ,cdbl(0))` would fail

Note that this function checks for type equality, so comparing integers to longs, doubles to singles, etc. all fails. Comparing Null to Null passes, however.

Implement it:

```
?DblSafeCompare(cdbl(0.33) + cdbl(0.50) ,cdbl(0.83))
?DblSafeCompare(cdbl(0.331) + cdbl(0.50) ,cdbl(0.83))
```

Comment: Thanks for providing the code. Never thought it had to be that complicated. But now it works like a charm!

Comment: Note that the code I shared was for my use case. As such `DblSafeCompare(Null, Null)` is `True`, and `DblSafeCompare(1, CDbl(1))` is `False`

Answer (score 2):

Comparing floating point numbers is really an issue, if you try to do it without understanding of the nature of the floating numbers.

Here is a nice article about it - https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html and [How dangerous is it to compare floating point values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10334688/how-dangerous-is-it-to-compare-floating-point-values)

In general, this problem is so big, that some languages like C# have developed a specific class called `Decimal` which makes comparing run as it would be expected by a non-programmer. [Decimal info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/decimal). In `VBA`, a similar class is `Currency`. Thus

```
CCur(0.33) + CCur(0.50) = CCur(0.83)
```

Returns `True`. VBA supports the function `CDec`, which converts a double to a decimal number, but it does not support the class `Decimal`. Thus:

```
CDec(0.33) + CDec(0.50) = CDec(0.83)
```

would also return `True`. And is with some better accuracy than `Currency`. [CDec documentation.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/type-conversion-functions)

[image]

Comment: For fractions, when using modern VBA applications (can't find the year of introduction), I recommend using the `Decimal` data type, not the `Currency` data type (`CDec` not `CCur`). Decimal is a larger data type, that supports more precise values. Currency is limited to 4 decimals. Decimal is a non-floating number with 29 significant digits.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth - unfortunately `Decimal` is not supported by VBA. However, the `CDec` function is quite a good alternative indeed.

Comment: Well, not supported might be sort of true. You can't declare a decimal. But you can save one in a variant. See the following example: `Public Sub TestDec(): 
    Dim dec1 As Variant: 
    Dim dec2 As Variant:
    dec1 = CDec(0.3301111) + CDec(0.5):
    dec2 = CDec(0.8301111) :
    Debug.Print dec1 = dec2 :
End Sub`
This prints `True` in office 2010. You can also store decimals in Microsoft Access. Sorry for the bad formatting

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth - true. I wanted to edit my comment, but 5 minutes have already passed :)