# VBA identical nrs not matching in if statement

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, trailing

I apologise, I realise this may have been asked a gazillion times already but I've tried looking and I can't find a situation like mine. I'm still learning, and I've never posted here before either so please be gentle with me.

I am working in Excel VBA. I have two cells (PICKAmt and INVAamt, same sheet) and they each have the exact same number in them, e.g. 399.80.

1. Even after formatting the cell to 0.00 VBA still reads them both as "399.8", but also still says they are not the same
2. They are both "Doubles"
3. This same calculation worked under the exact same circumstances on a different sheet
4. My code says:

   ```
   Private Function INVACalc(ByVal INVAamt As Double, Holdcell As String, lastcell1 As String) As Double   
   Dim PICKAmt As Double  
   Dim APSDamt As Double  
   Dim lastcell3 As String  
   Dim SUND As String  
   Dim APIE As String

   Worksheets("GL").Activate  
   Range(lastcell1).Offset(0, 9).NumberFormat = "0.00"  
   Range(lastcell1).Offset(0, 9).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("AL:AL"))         'add up total of all lines  
   PICKAmt = Range(lastcell1).Offset(0, 9).Value  
   If PICKAmt = INVAamt Then    
      'do stuff  
   Else  
     'do something else  
   End if
   ```

It goes straight to the "Else", as if the two amounts are not identical, which they are. They have no extra spaces or characters. The only difference I can pick up between them is that the INVAAmt cell is formatted as "Custom" and the PICKAmt cell is formatted as "Number", but again, this same code does the job just fine on other sheets with the same formatting. I am at a loss.

Comment: Do subtract one number from another to see the difference. Dont rely on formatted value. If there is a difference, it will go to `Else`.

Comment: I've done that - there is no difference.

Comment: Do you mean `debug.print(PICKAmt - INVAamt)` or `debug.print(INVAamt - PICKAmt)` returns 0?

Comment: Well this is interesting... last night I did the subtraction in the sheet itself, and not the code, it came to 0. This morning when I saw shahkalpeshp's comment I added the line to the code and ran it again, expecting it to be pure 0. What I got was this: -1.13686837721616E-13.... I was not expecting that

Comment: Any suggestions on how to get around it?

Comment: Either `If Format(PICKAmt,"0.00") = Format(INVAamt,"0.00") then`

Or `If Abs(PICKAmt-INVAAmt) < 0.001` then

Comment: @CDP1802 - the first option worked. I am new enough to not understand WHY it worked, so feel free to explain it to me. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the way decimals are represent in binary as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47814134/comparing-doubles-returns-false). The 'same' decimal can have more than one floating point representations, for example

```vb
Sub explain()
   Dim n As Double, m As Double, k As Double
   n = 0.6
   m = 0.3 + 0.3
   k = 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1
   Debug.Print Format(m - n, "0.000000000000000000")
   Debug.Print Format(k - n, "0.000000000000000000")   
End Sub
```

First result is `0.000000000000000000` the second `0.000000000000000111`. One solution is to format the doubles as strings and compare the strings.

```vb
If Format(PICKAmt,"0.00") = Format(INVAamt,"0.00") Then
```