# Making a query between three access tables does not return value

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOrSI.png)[image]I have three Access tables. I tried to make a query depend on date, but the query does not return any value.

```
SELECT Sum(income2.mony) AS SumOfmony, Sum(outcome.mony) AS SumOfmony1, Sum(PT.PT_Paid) AS SumOfPT_Paid, Sum(PT.PT_Remain) AS SumOfPT_Remain, PT.PT_Date
FROM (PT INNER JOIN income2 ON PT.PT_Date = income2.dat) INNER JOIN outcome ON PT.PT_Date = outcome.[dat&time]
GROUP BY PT.PT_Date;
```

[image]

Comment: Can you add the data that is in the tables and what you expect the outcome of the query to be, please? Without seeing the data, no-one will be able to make a helpful suggestion other than "Check the PT_Date/Dat/Dat&Time values and make sure they match"

Comment: type of data  are the same in feild (dat,dat&time&Pt_Date) is date and time format

Comment: Your question's tag is incorrect. Please, fix them so that people wouldn't confuse.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1BooHc9XZauMh-TXLz0CtnweN9_YdrnVx

Comment: please show some data. my guess is that the time section in these fields contains non-identical values, and therefor do not join.

Comment: yes marian there is unidentical dates.but i think it should to give me zero.if i removed the joins it giving me values

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want subqueries, not joins. `INNER JOIN` returns no records on unmatched results.

Then, there's an additional problem: dates can store fractions of seconds. Comparing dates for equality leads to trouble in Access (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47789884/7296893) for an example)

Try querying your external tables using these subqueries:

```
SELECT Sum(income2.mony) FROM income2 WHERE DateDiff("s",PT.PT_Date, income2.dat) = 0
SELECT Sum(outcome.mony) FROM outcome WHERE DateDiff("s",PT.PT_Date, outcome.[dat&time]) = 0
```

Implemented:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT Sum(income2.mony) FROM income2 WHERE DateDiff("s",PT.PT_Date, income2.dat) = 0) As SumOfmony,
    (SELECT Sum(outcome.mony) FROM outcome WHERE DateDiff("s",PT.PT_Date, outcome.[dat&time]) = 0) AS SumOfmony1,
    Sum(PT.PT_Paid) AS SumOfPT_Paid, Sum(PT.PT_Remain) AS SumOfPT_Remain, PT.PT_Dat
FROM PT
GROUP BY PT.PT_Date;
```