MS Access failed to retrieve data from part of the records (bug or something wrong in SQL ?)
I lost about half a day and nearly got totally mad !
The problematic database is just 88.5 MB but comprises 815921 records (weather data: 1 date field + 13 decimal number fields).
My VB code failed to extract and read about 5% of the records, though most of them were treated correctly-
The desired data are first extracted by a query form, requiring that 4 of the fields are NOT NULL. This gives a set of 262308 records. From there the query form calculates new variables from the 4 NOT NULL fields by VB code (e.g. N: Nord—([Chrono] calls the Nord—() function with the [Chrono] parameter).
The problem: though the query comprises only records without NULL values, its recordset comprises many records which have only NULL fields apart of the date field used to retrieve them.
The code looks as follows:
Function SO_Test(ByVal Chrono) As Single
    Dim db As Database, CT As Recordset, Durée As Single
    Set db = CurrentDb()
    Set CT = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * " _
        & "FROM [MesuresOK] WHERE [Chrono] = #" _
        & Format(Chrono, "m\/d\/yyyy hh:mm:ss") _
        & "#;", dbOpenDynaset)
    While Not CT.EOF
        Select Case CT![Rafale°]
            Case 181 To 269
                SO_Test— = Vecteur(225, CT![Rafale°]) * CT![Rafale] * Durée
            Case NULL
                Stop    ''' here we land though [Rafale°] = 236 in the database ''' 
            Case Else
                SO_Test = 0
        End Select
        CT.MoveNext
    Wend
    CT.Close  
End Function

Note that the desired test record is well retrieved (CT.EOF is NOT NULL), but  VT![Rafale°]  and   VT![Rafale°]  are both NULL, leading to errors in the following procedure. This record's value as seen on the query form is 236 as it should be.
"Compacting and Repairing" the database (~3×) didn't help. I then suspected the presence of non-printing characters or the like and exported the data to MS Excel, transformed everything first to text then back to dates and numbers and finally imported all data back to MS Access again. No Success, the value "236" of this test record is still interpreted as NULL !
At the end, I found by accident that the problem diappears (hopefully permanently) when adding one more condition to the SQL query:
'''''   & "#;", dbOpenDynaset)   ''''' fails
& "# AND [Rafale°] > 0;", dbOpenDynaset)    ''''' OK

Now this record is correctly retrieved and CT![Rafale°] is 236 .
Is this a bug or did I oversee something important in the SQL code ?
Please remember that 95% of the records are correctly retrieved with all their values, without the additional condition " AND [Rafale°] > 0" ……

"but VT![Rafale°] and VT![Rafale°]" - looks like same field to me. Strongly advise not to use punctuation/special characters in naming convention.

Needs some description of the datatypes, how the data is stored (in Access tables presumably .. no?) Sample data illustrating the problem would help immensely. I'm also not sure why you say the query is only non-Null but the recordset has many nulls .... Its also a bit of a strange function  - why are you stopping in the middle? What is the function supposed to actually return? You seem to be calculating many values in the loop, but only returning one of them ... which is confusing.

Also, to be honest, case NULL just feels wrong. Equality with Null usually means trouble.

A consideration is that time in Access is a floating point number, so [Chrono] = #"         & Format(Chrono, "m\/d\/yyyy hh:mm:ss") might fail even though they are the same time down to the second (see https://stackoverflow.com/q/47789884/7296893, there's also a solution there)

As [Chrono] is Date/Time in the database, the SQL query must have it between # … # in the correct US format. The records are always retrieved correctly (CT.EOF never NULL), [Chrono] is OK but all other number values are NULL when not adding '& "# AND [Rafale°] > 0' at the end of the SQL query…

Is MesuresOK a table, or is it a query that has joins in it? It it is a query, then any left join to some child record that does not exist will always return null columns for that child table that does not exist.  Do a simple quick test against that table, and hit ctrl-g to get to immediate/debug window, and type in this: ? dcount("*",[MesuresOK], "[Chrono] is null").  ---  do a dcount testing each of the columns used - do any return a count for null?

Mesures (and MesuresOK) are tables. Your dcount query returns an error ("Undefined external name") but it's clear: Chrono is mandatory, there are no records with NULL value. The retrieved records have correct [Chrono] values, but the fields [Rafale°] and [Rafale] returned by the SQL query are all NULL, despite the fact that all these values are NOT null. in the table. Adding an additional condition in the SQL  query surprisingly solves the pronblem…

Ok the issue of course for a "null" value, then the expression your have for the case statement will not evaluate correctly.
In other words, in VBA code, you can't use nor go
 CT!SomeColumn = null

So, null expressions are considered "invalid" expressions.
So, with above, you can say use
isnull(CT!SomeColumn) = true

So, in your case, you have to test, or "cast" the null expression to a non null value when using case statements.
Hence, I suggest this code:
While Not CT.EOF
    Select Case Nz(CT![Rafale°], 0)
        Case 181 To 269
            SO_Test— = Vecteur(225, CT![Rafale°]) * CT![Rafale] * Durée
        Case 0
            ' column is null or empty ""
            Stop    ''' here we land though [Rafale°] = 236 in the database '''
        Case Else
            SO_Test = 0
    End Select
    CT.MoveNext
Wend
CT.Close

So, even without a Select Case statement, you could never have used
 If CT![Rafale°] = null then      -- NOT ALLOWED

You have to use
 If isnull(CT![Rafale°]) then

or
 If isnull(CT![Rafale°]) = true then

Or, you could use:
 if nz(CT![Rafale°],0) = 0 then

So, a Select Case statement is in effect behind a simple series of "if/then" statements, and as such, you are required to use valid expressions for each case statement, of which "some expression = null" is NEVER a valid expression.
The only real exception to the above rule?
When writing SQL statements, you can do this:
 select ID, FirstName FROM tblPeople WHERE FirstName Is Null

However, in VBA code? You simply can't use a standard logical compare of "some expression = null", but are required to use Nz(), or IsNull() when dealing with null columns.
Now, if your data can have both 0, and a null value?
Then you have to dump the use of the case statement, or you can say choose a value that never occurs, say perhaps Nz(CT!SomeColumn,-1).
Since nulls can be be difficult with a Select Case another great approach is to set the default value for the number column to 0, and then make the column required.
So, for text, or date columns, then I often allow null values, but for number values? I simply don't allow number columns to be null in any of my databases.

OK: This is an Access database, the fields are 1× Date/Time, all others numbers (integer or decimal).

Access db, fields = 1× Date/Time, all other numbers (integer or decimal). Twice Rafale° above is just a typing error (° is to distinguish the wind direction from its strength).
Case NULL was only added upon debugging AFTER the problem appeared. The values are also NULL without the Case NULL when I stop the code before "While Not CT.EOF".
The point is that the query doesn't comprise any record with NULL values. Any NULL value appearing here is an error, but without the added '& "# AND [Rafale°] > 0' ALL retrieved records (1 per Chrono value) comprise ONLY NULL values apart the Chrono field.

Well, if the source data does not have any null values, then you don't have to worry in your code. If the source data does have null values, then you need to wrap the top main case statement in a nz([your column],0). You don't have a choice here at all. You can't use a case statement with a null expression as I noted, and I noted why you can't.  If you don't have any null column data, then no null testing is required here.

The source data never contain null values, but the SQL query nevertheless always returns erroneously null values as long as I don't add an additional condition such as " AND [Rafale°] > 0 ", which condition is always met.
My question is whether this is a bug, or whether my original SQL query is wrong:
Set AT = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT TOP 1 [Chrono], [Vent], [Vent°], [Rafale], [Rafale°] " _
& "FROM [Mesures] WHERE [Chrono] = #" _
& Format(Chrono, "m/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss") & "#;", dbOpenDynaset)

The record with the desired [Chrono] value is always retrieved but erroneous NULL values are always returned for the 4 fields [Vent], [Vent°], [Rafale] and [Rafale°].
… unless I add an additional condition as described above (what way around I discovered upon debugging) !

You going have to provide a reproducible example here. Is Mesures a table, or a query?

Mesures is a table. The [Chrono] value is provided by a query looking for valid [Rafale] and [Rafale°] values.
